# MongoDB with Node Index Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I'm currently using a node.js application to scan Twitter's API based on a set of parameters, and then uploading those JSON objects to a MongoDB database kept on MLab. I have connected to the database without issue, but my code will only upload ONE tweet before crashing. Here is the error message:

```
(node:62948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error index: test-database.test-collection.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5aecb49e205197f5e4f52e32') }
```

It seems to have something to do with the keys that I am using in the database? How can I write my code so that I don't have this issue. Here is my program right now:

```
var Twitter = require("twitter");
var config = require("./config");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb");
var twitterClient = new Twitter(config);
const assert = require("assert");

const dbName = "test-database";
const collectionName = "test-collection";
const url = "mongodb://user:password@ds113870.mlab.com:13870/test-database";

const param =  {follow: '21111098,958191744683782144,18061669,21111098,18061669,2891210047,1869975300,19394188,4107251,16056306,259459455,21111098,18061669,2891210047,1869975300,19394188,4107251,16056306,259459455,968650362,343041182,5558312,111671288,476256944,378631423,803694179079458816,30354991,224285242,45645232,235217558,20879626,150078976,278124059,102477372,249787913,381577682,15324851,435500714,823302838524739584,20597460,555355209,15745368,229966028,3001665106,2863210809,1397501864,78403308,253252536,47747074,1262099252,1284467173,92186819,169198625,600463589,413160266,1096059529,1095504170,1058520120,328679423,247334603,308794407,216503958,234128524,59969802,10615232,118740781,1383059977,2856787757,75364211,586730005,18632666,18632809,1249982359,339822881,365530059,216881337,3229124078,55677432,816683274076614656,26594419,1068481578,1068540380,19726613,13529632,18137749,3067974778,109071031,278094476,21406834,1129029661,970207298,357606935,236511574,145292853,76456274,456137574,33537967,941000686275387392,555474658,264219447,11650762,16160352,57065141,753693622692970497,21269970,238177562,389554914,11651202,214767677,515822213,16473577,1071402577,323490669,1480852568,2962923040,2987970190,811313565760163844,3145735852,266133081,41363507,109287731,14125897,946549322,361569788,15808765,1603426344,18695134,407039290,1099199839,183062944,60828944,325231436,14140370,17494010,1872999342,72198806,709389393811927041,21157904,213339899,2964174789,22195441,1061029050,460376288,382791093,106733567,43910797,24768753,18915145,240790556,2612307559,7270292,20546536,225921757,27044466,250188760,292495654,122124607,29201047,223166587,171598736,94154021,221162525,26062385,486694111,242555999,770121222,14845376,432895323,3219708271,217543151,81191343,2955485182,978029858,296361085,26533227,76649729,21669223,283130017,73303753,13218102,1648117711,1074480192,23022687,262756641,18170310,88784440,242836537,946946130,172858784,7429102,409719505,293131808,158470209,117501995,35567751,193794406,158890005,234374703,113355380,1074518754,87510313,233737858,291756142,1848942470,202206694,499268312'};

let newTweet = {
    name: "",
    text: "",
    followers: ""
}

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
  assert.equal(null,err);
  console.log("connected.");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection(collectionName);

  const insertDocument = function(db, callback){

    // THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS //
    collection.insert(newTweet)
  }

  twitterClient.stream('statuses/filter',param,function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
        newTweet.name = tweet.user.screen_name;
        newTweet.followers = tweet.user.followers_count;
        newTweet.text = (tweet.extended_tweet) ? tweet.extended_tweet.text : tweet.text;

        insertDocument(newTweet, function(){
          db.close();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the database immediately after inserting one tweet.

```
// stream.on('data', function(tweet) {

insertDocument(newTweet, function(){
   db.close();
});
```

Instead, close the connection on stream end.

```
stream.on('end', function() {
    db.close();
});
```

You are getting the Duplicate key issue, because you declared the newTweet object globally, which shares the same object for every tweet. Declare the tweet object inside the stream.on('data') handler function. i.e.

```
 stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
    let newTweet = {};
    newTweet.name = tweet.user.screen_name;
    newTweet.followers = tweet.user.followers_count;
```